# Find date before max date in python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a df like this:

```
Cust        Mat         Date        MaxPurchaseDate
90050416    23007545    2018-01-01  2018-01-29
90050416    23078691    2018-01-01  2019-02-27
90050416    30476395    2018-01-01  2018-10-01
90050416    13447085    2018-01-01  2018-06-18
90050416    30239844    2018-01-01  2018-09-17
```

The date column shows the purchase date and i have caluclate the MaxPurchaseDate with:

```
df['MaxPurchaseDate'] = df.groupby(['Cust', 'Mat']).Date.transform('max')
```

Now I need the second max date for each Group Cust, Mat. How can I do this? I tried it with:

```
df.groupby(['Cust', 'Mat'])['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(2).max())
```

But here juptyer runs a long time until I stop the kernel. Is there a good and a fast way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably you could extract all the dates into a list, sort the list, and after that, you will obtain at the end of your list the biggest values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then for second top2 is possible use [`GroupBy.nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
#changed sample data for 2 groups by Cust, Mat columns and different Date values
print (df)
       Cust       Mat        Date MaxPurchaseDate
0  90050416  23007545  2018-06-01      2018-01-29
1  90050416  23007545  2018-02-01      2019-02-27
2  90050416  30476395  2018-03-01      2018-10-01
3  90050416  30476395  2018-01-01      2018-06-18
4  90050416  30476395  2018-04-01      2018-09-17

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = (df.sort_values(['Cust', 'Mat','Date'], ascending=[True, True, False])
        .groupby(['Cust', 'Mat'])
        .nth(1)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
       Cust       Mat       Date MaxPurchaseDate
0  90050416  23007545 2018-02-01      2019-02-27
1  90050416  30476395 2018-03-01      2018-10-01
```

Or [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and filter second value by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df.sort_values(['Cust', 'Mat','Date'], ascending=[True, True, False])
df = df[df.groupby(['Cust', 'Mat']).cumcount().eq(1)]

print (df)
       Cust       Mat       Date MaxPurchaseDate
1  90050416  23007545 2018-02-01      2019-02-27
2  90050416  30476395 2018-03-01      2018-10-01
```

Comment: OK perfect. The second one is a really good choice. Thanks jezrael.